# pairwise comparisons between pairs of proportions in R with a correction for some multiple testing rather all possible multiple testing

Tags: r

Is it possible to get the multiple comparison adjustment in `pairwise.prop.test()` to use less than the full number of comparisons? For example, if I only care about 4 vs 1,2,3 (3 comparisons) below, I would multiply the p-values in the bottom row by 3 instead of 6 (which is the full number of pairwise comparisons) to do the Bonferroni adjustment. p.adjust has the n argument, but I can't figure out how to pass it through by doing something like

```
pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="bonferroni", p.adjust.n = 3, alternative="two.sided", correct = FALSE)
```

With Bonferroni, it's trivial, but much more involved with the other types of corrections.

Here's the result (with code below):

```
> b <- data.frame(
+     s=c(18,53,49,30),
+   pop=c(29,100,88,73),
+   reg=c("1","2","3","4")
+ )
> pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="none",alternative="two.sided", correct = FALSE)

    Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions 

data:  b$s out of b$pop 

  1     2     3    
2 0.387 -     -    
3 0.547 0.713 -    
4 0.056 0.122 0.065

P value adjustment method: none 
> pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="bonferroni", alternative="two.sided", correct = FALSE)

    Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions 

data:  b$s out of b$pop 

  1    2    3   
2 1.00 -    -   
3 1.00 1.00 -   
4 0.33 0.73 0.39

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

---

**Code:**

```
b <- data.frame(
    s=c(18,53,49,30),
  pop=c(29,100,88,73),
  reg=c("1","2","3","4")
)
pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="none",alternative="two.sided", correct = FALSE)
pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="bonferroni", alternative="two.sided", correct = FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done as part of `pairwise.prop.test()` as extra arguments are passed to `prop.test()` not `p.adjust()`.   Why not just use `p.adjust()` directly? `p.adjust(res$p.value[3, ], method = "bonferroni")`

Comment: You can also probably do this in a more principled (and maybe even more powerful way) via the `multcomp` package (and the `linfct` function within it)

Comment: @27ϕ9 That works. I will gladly accept if you want to write that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @27 ϕ 9's comment:

```
b <- data.frame(
    s=c(18,53,49,30),
    pop=c(29,100,88,73),
    reg=c("1","2","3","4")
)
unadj <- pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="none",alternative="two.sided")
p.adjust(unadj$p.value[3, ], method = "holm") 
pairwise.prop.test(x=b$s,n=b$pop,p.adjust.method="bonferroni", alternative="two.sided")
```